# Failed to install kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, upstream-branch

When attempting to compile my custom Linux kernel, the `sudo make modules_install` command failed, resulting in the following errors:

```
  INSTALL /lib/modules/5.14.0-rc7+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/blake2s-x86_64.ko
  SIGN    /lib/modules/5.14.0-rc7+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/blake2s-x86_64.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: : No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:83: /lib/modules/5.14.0-rc7+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/blake2s-x86_64.ko] Error 1
make[1]: *** Deleting file '/lib/modules/5.14.0-rc7+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/blake2s-x86_64.ko'
make: *** [Makefile:1777: modules_install] Error 2
```

How can I overcome this issue?

I also tried to compile the latest version (6.X) and also 5.1X.
Thank you all.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/820883/how-to-resolve-ssl-error-during-make-modules-install-command. You need either create a signing key or disable signing in kernel configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I get a similar error when building kernel 6.6.6 or 6.6.7 including the missing bss_file.c file. It took me forever to find the cause. It is very weird, despite it is "SSL errors" it seems to have nothing to do with that. For some reason it has to do with using ZSTD compression for kernel modules. I could trace it back to a kernel .config option. Try to change the following two options in the kernel .config file to the following, and then it should build fine:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_NONE=y
# CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_ZSTD is not set
```

I have no idea why that is related, but I changed configurations and diffed many .config files for a while until I realized it. The error message is not very helpful here.

For comparison, that are the last lines of my kernel build output when building with `make -j12 bindeb-pkg`

```
  DEPMOD  debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6
  INSTALL debian/linux-libc-dev/usr/include
  SIGN    debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/amd/amd-uncore.ko
  SIGN    debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/intel/intel-cstate.ko
  SIGN    debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/rapl.ko
  SIGN    debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/mce-inject.ko
  SIGN    debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/msr.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/amd/amd-uncore.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/intel/intel-cstate.ko
At main.c:298:
  SIGN    debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpuid.ko
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/rapl.ko
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/amd/amd-uncore.ko] Error 1
make[6]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/intel/intel-cstate.ko] Error 1
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/events/rapl.ko] Error 1
  SIGN    debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/mce-inject.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/msr.ko
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/mce-inject.ko] Error 1
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/msr.ko] Error 1
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpuid.ko
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpuid.ko] Error 1
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64.ko
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.6.6/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64.ko] Error 1
make[5]: *** [Makefile:1821: modules_install] Error 2
make[4]: *** [Makefile:2036: run-command] Error 2
make[3]: *** [debian/rules:17: binary-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: make -f debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:146: bindeb-pkg] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/home/root/linux-git/Makefile:1538: bindeb-pkg] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
 linux-git/ >
```

Comment: This advice helped in my case. I was building a Linux 6.5.0 kernel from GitHub based on the config from Ubuntu 23.10. Got exactly this error, and exactly the proposed fix helped.